# Bash script doesn't execute command from PATH

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I have this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${HADOOP_HOME}
$(hadoop fs -ls)
```

The output is:

```
/opt/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u2
./hello.sh: line 3: Found: command not found
```

So bash definitely sees HADOOP_HOME. I've set it in ~/.profile and added path to bin folder:

```
export HADOOP_HOME="/opt/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u2"
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

If I simply invoke command in console everything works but inside a script it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the problem with `echo ${HADOOP_HOME}` command.The one which causes the error is `$(hadoop fs -ls)`

You have to give the 3rd line in that script as `echo $(hadoop fs -ls)`. So the script will look like,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${HADOOP_HOME}
echo $(hadoop fs -ls)
```

If you give the command like this `$(hadoop fs -ls)`, bash parses it and find it's value. And the founded value is again parsed by bash.

Example:

```
$ var=4
$ $var
4: command not found
$ echo $var
4
```

IMO, the value or the output of the command `hadoop fs -ls` is `Found`, this string found was again parsed by bash when you give the command like this `$(hadoop fs -ls)`. So that the below error message displayed while executing the script `hello.sh`,

```
./hello.sh: line 3: Found: command not found
```